# EJB 3.1 JBoss 7.1.1 @EJB or JNDI none of them work

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jndi, ejb-3.1

My EJB-Project has one Entity-Class `Reservierung` and one interface `ReservierungLocal` (annotation `@Remote`) with the method `addReservierung` and a session bean `Reservierungsession` (annotation `@Stateless`) with the implementation of `addResrvierung`. With this project everything runs fine. The JNDI bindings are:

```
java:global/AutoKunde/Reservierungsession!local.ReservierungLocal
java:app/AutoKunde/Reservierungsession!local.ReservierungLocal
java:module/Reservierungsession!local.ReservierungLocal
java:jboss/exported/AutoKunde/Reservierungsession!local.ReservierungLocal
java:global/AutoKunde/Reservierungsession
java:app/AutoKunde/Reservierungsession
java:module/Reservierungsession
```

Then I have a dynamic web project where I put the EJB project in the classpath. Inside that project I have a servlet `ReservierungServlet`, a jsp file and the web.xml. Without any implemented code in the servlet everything works fine, without adding something. But it doesn't matter if I put an `@EJB` over `ReservierungLocal` or with `InitialContext` with JNDI there is always the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: local.ReservierungLocal from [Module "deployment.Reservierung.war:main" from Service Module Loader].
```

I tried all of the JNDI bindings but none of them work... the `@EJB` annotation doesn't work , too...what is the problem? Does anybody know??

Comment: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: local.ReservierungLocal" Class Not Found. Seems pretty obvious. Your client does not have access to the local interface class. Let me rephrase that: it is not on the classpath of the client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...i thought if i put the whole EJB Project into the class path of the Dynamic Web Project it would be in the class path..but it seems to be not so